# design points calculation based on rules defined in table

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

Have a database table which business / sales folks could and will keep modifying:

```
year from | year to | points
-----------------------------
1930      | 1943    | 20
-----------------------------
1944      | 1978    | 10
-----------------------------
1979      | 2012    | 07
-----------------------------
```

In future they could add points for each year thereafter (2013 , 2014 ...)

My problem is that the user will enter a date range and I am expected to calculate points based on date range:

> if date range is between 1932 - 2010 then points will be 20 ( 1932 is in the range 1930-1943) + 10 (the range 1944-1978 is fully included ) + 07 ( 2010 falls in the range 1979-2012) = 37

Now I don't want to make changes in my code should this confguration table be modified.

How do I approach this design? 
I did read a little and have a vague inkling about possible patterns (strategy / state) but without an actual sample code example (java) am not able to grasp or get clarity.

Any pointers and help is greatly appreciated

My basic rudimentary approach was:

> First retrieve these configurations and store in memory
>  
>   check user selected date range Ex 1991

Then the code gets messy ...

```
int points = 0;
if(entered_year > 1943) {
 points = points+20;
}
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Before thinking about possible patterns, you should think about how to apply this thinking into code:

> if date range is between 1932 - 2010 then points will be 20 ( 1932 ) + 10 ( this range is covered ) + 07 ( 2010 falls in this range ) = 37

You then say that the code gets messy and you provide the following example:

```
int points = 0;
if (entered_year > 1943) {
    points = points + 20;
}
// etc
```

But this is messy because it's hard coded. And when the table changes then you also need to change the code. Not sure if this is exactly what you are doing or it's just an unfortunate example to make a point, but just wanted to mention this.

With these being said, you should first try to write an algorithm that combines these two things together. Basically remove the hard codings and implement that thinking.

I would start with creating a record class for each table row, like so:

```
public class PointRecord { // or whatever name makes more sense
    private int yearFrom;
    private int yearTo;
    private int points;

    public PointRecord(int yearFrom, int yearTo, int points) {
        this.yearFrom = yearFrom;
        this.yearTo = yearTo;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getYearFrom() {
        return yearFrom;
    }

    public int getYearTo() {
        return yearTo;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

Then I would read all of the table from the database into a `List<PointRecord> configurations` in memory. I assume there won't be too many of these records in the database.

Then it's a matter of traversing the entire list and apply your rules:

```
int points = 0;
for (PointRecord pointRecord : configurations) {
    if (enteredYearFrom > pointRecord.getYearFrom()) {
        points = points + pointRecord.getPoints();
    }
    if (enteredYearTo < pointRecord.getYearTo()) {
        points = points + pointRecord.getPoints();
    }
    // rest of the rules you have
}
```

Multiple variations are possible:

- You could have the list in memory and reload it only if sales people change it;
- you could load the list every time you need to do this computation if that's not a performance issue;
- assuming the previous point, you could load only records that would make sense (depending on the entered range you could select the records that match), thus reducing the size of the list you load;
- depending on how complex those rules are and how good your SQL skills are, you might even do this with a query directly on the database (a SELECT with a properly constructed WHERE clause with another wrapping query with a SUM() aggregate on top of it might be possible;
- etc.

First try a simple algorithm that duplicates the logic you use to compute them manually, and if you are not satisfied with the result, you can then look for other patterns.